# ImportError: No module named serial

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, module, pyserial

I have a script written in Python 3 with 3.3.5 installed, and I am getting this error from the terminal whenever I try to run it.  I am using a Mac, OSX 10.7.5

I have already installed `pyserial` (using pip) for python 3. In order to do this, I first installed pip using:

```
$ curl -O http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py
$ sudo python3 distribute_setup.py
$ curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py
$ sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

I then installed `pyserial` with:

```
$sudo pip3 install pyserial
```

I run the script with Python Launcher and I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named serial
```

The error is at the line which says

```
import serial
```

I located `pyserial` in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages`. I am really stumped and have no clue why I am getting this error.

I tried the following in Terminal:

```
$ python3
>>> import serial
>>> serial
<module 'serial' from '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages/serial/__init__.py'>
```

To me it looks like there isn't an issue with the directory.  Is that a fair assumption, since Python instantly looks through that directory when I try it with the command line, or is it different when I'm running a script?

I'm very new to all of this so any sort of help and patience would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks.

EDIT: For anyone else looking at this having a similar problem, I didn't *really* fix it, but I worked around it by just running my program with eclipse using the PyDev plugin.  If that's an option for you, worked like a charm for me.

Comment: Can you execute `pip3 list` and paste the result here? Also, is `PYTHONPATH` set?

Comment: @Trein  pip3 list gives me the following: 

    "distribute (0.6.49)  
    pip (1.5.4)  
    pyserial (2.7)  
    setuptools (3.4.4) "

I am not quite sure what I am doing, but I tried setting PYTHONPATH with a tutorial I found.  Here's what I did:  

    export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/lib/python3.3/site-packages  

It didn't fix it though.  I get the sense that this is not too complicated a problem, but it's giving me a huge headache.  Thanks!

Comment: Everything seems to be correct. My last guess is that `Python Launcher` is using the incorrect interpreter (maybe it is using Python 2.7). Go to preferences and check it out.

Answer (score 12):

On my ubuntu 14.4 with python 2.7 as default, I installed pyserial for python3 (which my IDE is using actually) with the help of following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

Answer (score 1):

First use the two commands (**which pip** & **which python**) to get the exact path of the python and pip commands.
After this only you will be able to determine the exact issue.

Comment: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip

which python gives me python 2.7, but I am executing it through python launcher 3.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: I am not sure but this could be issue.
Try using relative path for python command so that it picks up your python 3.x. 
Like instead of using **python** you should use **/xyzpath_for_python3.x/python**

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was solved by running the script importing serial in a user (not administrative) context. Windows, not Mac, so YMMV.

Comment: In hindsight, that probably had something to do with the proliferation of Python installs in the computer, with the user console resolving to a different installation compared to the administrative one.