# pyserial library not found

Tags: python, macos, pyserial

I am getting an import error using `pyserial` on `mac`.

I have `pip` downloaded it and easy installed it but it doesn't seem to be recognised.

This is the error:

```
File "python.server", line 2, in <module>
    import serial
ImportError: No module named serial
```

It's not finding any problem with the first line `'import http'` so it is definitely something specific to `pyserial`.

Comment: install for `IDLE(system)` and call from another editor ? Validate your module paths !

Comment: You try whit these https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3hhe8a/when_i_import_serial_i_get_the_error_messageno/ or try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23378208/importerror-no-module-named-serial

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108428/pyserial-no-module-named-tools

Comment: Thanks guys, solved it but not totally sure how....